# AWS EB Deploy shows missing Dockerrun.aws.json after deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my application to Elastic Beanstalk (running docker) but during the deploy it always fails with something like this:

```
Activity execution failed, because: cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory  cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory  2ba4cc7f9cb0a66db0ab1be8736ba96bffbb1c96a219cf5e888f99a964ae4f2a
```

As far as I understand Dockerrun.aws.josn file is not required if Dockerfile is present and I don't see any reason why we should have it.

My Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# create source directory
RUN rm -rf /var/www
RUN mkdir /var/www

# update and upgrade ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# install nginx
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

# install php 7
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-xml php7.0-curl

# install php mysql
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0-mysql

# install php mbstring
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0-mbstring

# install php mcrypt
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0-mcrypt

# install git
RUN apt-get install -y git

# install zip and unzip
RUN apt-get install -y zip unzip 

ADD . /var/www

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

Our application source files are in the same directory as the Dockerfile.
I took the example of file structure and the dockerfile it self from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-singlecontainer-deploy.html

We use the same Dockerfile to build the app using CodeBuild and it has no error. also locally I can build that app without any problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone has the same issue - I contacted AWS suppord and found out that it is not actually a error, more like informative thing. What killed the deploy here was a issue with nginx conf.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comment bellow the issue might be not in the missing `Dockerrun.aws.json` but in something else.

To pin point the actual issue I've had to ssh into the box and check the logs. In my case it was

```sh
eb ssh
less /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/unexpected-quit.log
```